# Angular2 auth guard with http request and observables

Tags: authentication, angular, angular2-routing, observable, angular2-http

i am currently implementing an angular2 example application with spring boot as backend. I am having some problems with the frontend auth guard mechanism and observables.

I am trying to achieve:

1. when someone enters a protected route the auth guard should check if a user 
   is already set in the auth service variable
2. if it is not set then a http request should be issued to check if a session is available
3. the service method should return a true/false value (asynchronously because of the possible http request)
4. if service returns false the auth guard should redirect to login page
5. auth guard should return true/false so the route can either be activated or not

My code currently looks like this (i am using RC5 btw.):

Auth Guard

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs/Rx";
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    var authenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated();
    var subject = new Subject<boolean>();
    authenticated.subscribe(
        (res) => {
          console.log("onNext guard: "+res);
          if(!res && state.url !== '/signin') {
            console.log("redirecting to signin")
            this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
          }
          subject.next(res);
        });
    return subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Auth Service

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {User} from "./user.interface";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Http, Response, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import {environment} from "../environments/environment";
import {Observable, Observer, Subject} from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private authenticatedUser : User;
  constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http) {}

  signupUser(user: User) {
  }


  logout() {
    //do logout stuff
    this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
  }

  isAuthenticated() : Observable<boolean> {
    var subject = new Subject<boolean>();
    if (this.authenticatedUser) {
      subject.next(true);
    } else {
      this.http.get(environment.baseUrl + '/user')
        .map((res : Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => {
          console.log("next: returning true");
          this.authenticatedUser = User.ofJson(res);
          subject.next(true);
        }, (res) => {
          console.log("next: returning false");
          subject.next(false);
        });
    }
    return subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

The problem is: the guard never allows the router component to activate, even though when i am logged in.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: see edit, the router component never activates, even when i successfully logged in. If i don't use any observables it works fine, but i can't use http requests then so that is not an option for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
return subject.asObservable();
```

to

```
return subject.asObservable().first();
```

The router waits for the observable to complete. `first()` makes it complete after the first event.

Comment: Thanks this solves a part of the problem. What happens now is that when i click on a protected route it always prevents the route from activating and prints the log message. But when i enter valid auth credentials in the login screen and the server replies with 200 OK, i still can't access the protected route. When i press f5 and refresh the page  i suddenly can access the protected route. This is probably due to the authenticatedUser variable in the service class where i store the user object, but i am not sure why, any ideas?

Comment: You could try using a `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject` in `isAuthenticated()`. Currently if `this.authenticatedUser` is `true` you emit `true` but at this point there is no subscriber yet. This code part is executed sync and `true` is emitted before `return subject.asObservable()`  is executed and the caller of `isAuthenticated()` won't receive this event.

Comment: I had to use a combination of BehavorSubject (Service) and ReplaySubject (guard), but it's working as expected now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out :)

Comment: @Tim Can you share some code examples of your working solution? I'm running into the same issue and seeing a working example would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: all i did was to use a replaySubject in the guard, a behavioursubject in the service and add .take(1) in the guards return clause